# How do I sync iPad Notes without Mail?

Tags: ipad

The default Notes app on the iPad is fine for my note taking needs.  I see how it syncs through iTunes to Mail, but if one doesn't use Mail for e-mail management, is there any other way to sync and view the iPad notes on the desktop?

(We use Eudora for mail management, and Apple's Mail is not great if all you want to do is view your notes with it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple [iCloud](http://www.icloud.com) can be used for this.

For third party applications that support Android as well see http://www.evernote.com/ and [Penultimate](http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/penultimate/id354098826?mt=8)

Evernote does good syncing

For general file sync see [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) or [wuala](http://www.wuala.com)

If you need more "Enterprisy" features you could have a look at [DME from Excitor](http://www.excitor.com) or [Cortado](http://www.cortado.com)